# Adding units to pgfplotstable header

Tags: tables, external-files, pgfplotstable

I am plotting a table using a semicolon separated `.csv` file and `pgfplotstable`.
The table shows up fine, but i need to have units within the head of the table.

like this:

[image]

what I have looks like this:

[image]

How can i add those mesurments to my header?

MWE

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[allowlitunits]{siunitx}
\begin{filecontents}{test.dat}
        Zeit;100;90;80;70;60;50;40;30;20;10
        0;0.195;0.156;0.13;0.155;0.107;0.94;0.74;0.43;0.46;0.03
        15;0.219;0.171;0.157;0.147;0.125;0.106;0.96;0.09;0.64;0.45
        30;0.237;0.189;0.177;0.168;0.138;0.12;0.113;0.108;0.75;0.57
        45;0.265;0.208;0.197;0.192;0.16;0.141;0.132;0.126;0.95;0.75
        60;0.296;0.228;0.217;0.221;0.182;0.16;0.151;0.148;0.108;0.82
        75;0.317;0.249;0.239;0.248;0.206;0.177;0.171;0.164;0.125;0.95
        90;0.344;0.271;0.265;0.271;0.232;0.197;0.192;0.185;0.142;0.108
        105;0.404;0.293;0.286;0.297;0.259;0.217;0.214;0.206;0.165;0.122
        120;0.433;0.316;0.304;0.323;0.281;0.241;0.236;0.237;0.181;0.136
        135;0.447;0.339;0.326;0.354;0.312;0.268;0.264;0.255;0.2;0.151
        150;0.473;0.363;0.352;0.383;0.334;0.285;0.283;0.273;0.219;0.166
        165;0.489;0.387;0.376;0.411;0.365;0.308;0.307;0.296;0.24;0.181
        180;0.526;0.412;0.401;0.443;0.386;0.331;0.331;0.32;0.267;0.193
        195;0.59;0.438;0.425;0.48;0.414;0.353;0.357;0.344;0.284;0.212
        210;0.634;0.464;0.45;0.504;0.443;0.375;0.382;0.368;0.305;0.225
        225;0.684;0.49;0.476;0.537;0.476;0.405;0.408;0.383;0.327;0.237
        240;0.704;0.517;0.505;0.57;0.499;0.438;0.435;0.418;0.35;0.26
        255;0.739;0.544;0.534;0.604;0.527;0.465;0.461;0.444;0.377;0.277
        270;0.758;0.577;0.558;0.638;0.557;0.493;0.489;0.472;0.395;0.294
        285;0.809;0.599;0.586;0.671;0.588;0.527;0.51;0.505;0.424;0.31
        300;0.858;0.627;0.615;0.703;0.618;0.557;0.543;0.538;0.442;0.327         
    \end{filecontents}
\begin{document}


    \pgfplotstableset{
        begin table=\begin{longtable},
            end table=\end{longtable},
    }

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=semicolon,
    header=true,    
    columns/Zeit/.style={fixed,fixed ,column type=r},
    columns/100/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3,column type=c},
    columns/90/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3,column type=c},
    columns/80/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3,column type=c},
    columns/70/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3,column type=c},
    columns/60/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3,column type=c},
    columns/50/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3,column type=c}, 
    columns/40/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3,column type=c},
    columns/30/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3,column type=c},
    columns/20/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3,column type=c}, 
    columns/10/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3,column type=c},     
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule\endhead}, 
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
    ]{test.dat}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify what to use for the column header using the key `column name={...}`. If you use a `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` loop together with `columns/#1/.estyle` (the `e` stands for `expanded`), you can define the column headers automatically based on the percentage value:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[pdftex]{lscape}
\usepackage[allowlitunits]{siunitx}
\begin{filecontents}{test.dat}
        Zeit;100;90;80;70;60;50;40;30;20;10
        0;0.195;0.156;0.13;0.155;0.107;0.94;0.74;0.43;0.46;0.03
        15;0.219;0.171;0.157;0.147;0.125;0.106;0.96;0.09;0.64;0.45
        30;0.237;0.189;0.177;0.168;0.138;0.12;0.113;0.108;0.75;0.57
        45;0.265;0.208;0.197;0.192;0.16;0.141;0.132;0.126;0.95;0.75
        60;0.296;0.228;0.217;0.221;0.182;0.16;0.151;0.148;0.108;0.82
    \end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \pgfplotstableset{
        begin table=\begin{longtable},
            end table=\end{longtable},
    }
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{100,90,...,10}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\concentration{#1/100*0.25}
    \pgfplotstableset{
        columns/#1/.estyle={
            fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3,
            column type=p{4.5em},
            column name={\SI[round-mode=places,round-precision=3]{\concentration}{\mol\per\liter} (\SI{#1}{\percent})}}
    }
}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=semicolon,
    header=true,    
    columns/Zeit/.style={fixed,fixed ,column type=r},
    every head row/.style={
            before row=\toprule,
            after row=\midrule\endhead
        }, 
    every last row/.style={
            after row=\bottomrule
        }
    ]{test.dat}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted, sadly I'm not able to compile this code. after removing the `lscape` and `landscape` I still get:
`pgfplots: Could not read table file 'test.dat'. In case you int for details). ]{test.dat}`

Comment: @Rico: It works for me. Is the `test.dat` file written to the directory correctly?

Comment: interestingly it works with writeLaTeX, too. But on my own PC `filecontents` nor putting everything in file named `test.csv` works.

Comment: @Rico: What version of PGFPlots are you using? Can you try removing the `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` command and the `longtable` stuff to see if it works then?

Comment: I am using Package: pgfplots 2013/03/17 v1.8 Data Visualization (1.8-3-gaf58a29)

Comment: don't know where the problem is, rebooted my pc, and made a new file where I pasted your answer. Works now. I'm afraid there will be follow up questions soon :)