# Externalize pgfplotstable with csv file

Tags: tables, pgfplots, external-files, pgfplotstable

This is a direct follow-up question to this: [Adding units to pgfplotstable header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117788/adding-units-to-pgfplotstable-header)

After fixing the output I tried outsourcing the `table`. After figuring out that `standalone` does not work with `longtable` (thanks to @Jake) I removed that, but even then every time i try to compile with `pdfLaTeX` I get this error:

> ! Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 't3.dat'. In case you inten
>   ded to provide inline data: maybe TeX screwed up your end-of-lines? Try `row se
>   p=crcr' and terminate your lines with \\` (refer to the `pgfplotstable` manual for details).

where `t3.csv` is the file where all the data is stored.

My file currently looks like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[allowlitunits]{siunitx}

\begin{document}   
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{100,90,...,10}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\concentration{#1/100*0.25}
        \pgfplotstableset{
            columns/#1/.estyle={
                fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3,
                column type=p{4.5em},
                column name={\SI[round-mode=places,round-precision=3]{\concentration}{\mol\per\liter} (\SI{#1}{\percent})}}
        }
    }
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=semicolon,
    header=true,    
    columns/Zeit/.style={fixed,fixed ,column type=r},
    every head row/.style={
        before row=\toprule,
        after row=\midrule\endhead
    }, 
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule
    }
    ]{t3.dat}

\end{document}
```

So to summarize the whole thing, I tried 2 ways to include this table:

1. Using the `standalone` class and including the file with `\includestandalone{subdir/filename}`
2. Using a file without any preamble and `\documentclass` and using the `\input{subdir/filename}` method.

Still I'm not able to determine what causes this error. Running Windows 7 and TeXStudio

### EDIT

it looks like I am not able to write a file into any directory. so the question should be, why am I not able to write a file?

Comment: Hm, it compiles fine for me using the first method (I didn't try the second). Is the `t3.dat` file in the `subdir` folder?

Comment: Did you try running TeXStudio as administrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I fixed it but it wasn't as spectacular as I thought

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[allowlitunits]{siunitx}
\begin{document}   
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{100,90,...,10}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\concentration{#1/100*0.25}
    \pgfplotstableset{
        columns/#1/.estyle={
            fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3,
            column type=p{4.5em},
            column name={\SI[round-mode=places,round-precision=3]{\concentration}{\mol\per\liter} (\SI{#1}{\percent})}}
    }
}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=semicolon,
header=true,    
columns/Zeit/.style={fixed,fixed ,column type=r},
every head row/.style={
    before row=\toprule,
    after row=\midrule
}, 
every last row/.style={
    after row=\bottomrule
}
]{t3.dat}

\end{document}
```

looks pretty much the same but since `standalone` does not work with `longtable` I removed this part:

```
\pgfplotstableset{
    begin table=\begin{longtable},
        end table=\end{longtable},
}
```

what I forgot was to remove the `\endhead` command within `after row` (see first Question)

And I moved all files to the same directory, not sure if this is that important. It is not that pretty but works for me.